# update by query performance in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am newbie to ElasticSearch . I am trying to update all the records using following inline script.

ES Version : 5.1.1
POST http://localhost:9200/index_1,index_2/type/_update_by_query?ignore_unavailable=true

```
{
    "script": {
        "inline": "if(ctx._source.containsKey(\"status\")){ctx._source.status.name = 'UPDATED_STATUS_NAME';ctx._source.status.value = 'UPDATED_STATUS_VALUE';ctx._source.status.name = 'UPDATED_STATUS_NAME';ctx._source.status.value = 'UPDATED_STATUS_VALUE';}"
    }
}
```

Now consider the following scenario:

1] we hit update by query on ES

2] step 1 is in progress and we get another update request

3] we hit update by query on ES again

4] Now 2 update queries are in progress

I want to know how ElasticSearch will behave in such condition

1] will there be conflicts ?

2] will ES be down since we are hitting update by query on thousand's of documents twice or may be the number of times user wants to perform update operation
or **rather any risk in above operation**

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

While updating if version conflict of document.

Processing depends on query param contain (?conflicts=proceed? )

1 Passed  Will escape version conflicting document rest will get updated .

2 Not passed then document get updated until it get version conflict and operation get abort.

NOTE: In Neither of the case updated documents **are not rolled** back like RDBS.